# SQLite3::SQLException: no such table for Rails app

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I'm having some problems with signing up in my rails app, with the error coming up of
    **"column email is not unique"**
despite the fact I know that I haven't used this particular email address before. I thought I'd check my database anyway, and ran:

```
rails console -e=test
```

looking at `Users.all` to see what records were saved. However, not only are none of them saved, but I get the error:

```
**SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: SELECT "users".* FROM "users"**
```

But in my schema, it clearly says

```
  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
  end
```

and nothing happens if I keep trying to `db:migrate` or `db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development`.
Any suggestions please?

Edit: running **`rails console`** (not -e=test) results in this:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, email: "", encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2014-09-22 14:03:39", updated_at: "2014-09-22 14:03:39", provider: nil, uid: nil>]>
```

Comment: `rails console -e=test` opening your test console not development console so try `rails console` and then see database there

Comment: are you working in the same directory? coz it is a common mistake.

Comment: Did you run: `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:create db:migrate` before running any other command?

Comment: I did db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development, and also tried without the rails_env bit.

Answer (score 2):

it looks like you haven't created your database in your test environment. Run:

```
rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test 
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

that should hopefully solve it